# Multiply columns by factor depending on column ID

Tags: r

```
a <- structure(c(1017, 63, 9184, 9782, 42, 1467, 84, 11829, 11989, 
49, 1459, 93, 11399, 11302, 42, 188, 14, 1530, 1463, 7, 189, 
20, 1647, 1569, 6), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("NC_013663.1_297_-", 
"NC_013663.1_553_-", "NC_013663.1_553_+", "NC_013663.1_554_-", 
"NC_013663.1_555_-"), c("CL1", "CL2", "CL3", "CL4", "CL5")))
```

For my data frame above I would like to multiply the columns that contains L1,L2 and L3 with the factor "0.1343109", and those containing L4,L5 and L6 with the factor "1".

I guess this can be done with an `ifelse` function, but not sure how to set it up.

Comment: How does *"multiply ... with the factor '1'"* differ from ... do nothing?

Comment: Its the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of columns with substring L1 to L3 using `grep`.  Extract the columns, multiply with the value 0.1343109 and update by assigning back to the columns.  (Note - multiplying by 1 returns the same value, thus it is left as such)

```
i1 <- grep("L[1-3]$", colnames(a))
a[, i1] <- a[, i1] * 0.1343109
```